# Visual Studio 2012, formatting C#, insert a space before variable incrementing on AutoFormat

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, formatting

When I AutoFormat my C# code in Visual Studio 2012, I would like a space in between my variable and the "++" or "--" operators, ie:

`int i = 0; i++;`

When I AutoFormat the code, I would like a space between "i" and "++", ie:

`int i = 0; i ++;`

I would expect an option under Options, Text Editor, C#, Formatting, Spacing; but I don't see anything that applies.

Comment: Why do you need something like that, I would be hard to read IMO.

Comment: This is not a usual variant of any standard I know (that's credited as being any good, at least), and has no option to configure in VS, likely because of its utter uselessness and potential to confuse.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how unconstructive opinions on code formatting are relevant.  Would you like to make fun of the bands I like too?

Comment: Code formatting is not just for _you_, as are your tastes in music.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there isn't a space formatting option for handling the increment/decrement operators in Visual Studio 2012, or any version as far as I can tell.

Like the commenters pointed out, it seems as it's almost universally practiced that the `++`  and `--` operators come immediately before or after the variable it's operating on. I understand your position on preference for code formatting, so here's a few suggestions if resolving this issue has that much impact on your daily coding life:

Check out ReSharper, a productivity tool for Visual Studio that has the capability to extend auto formatting. In fact, they have a whole section dealing with spacing around operators:

[image: operator spacing]

Though not on the list, you could suggest a possible implementation of the `++` and `--` operators to the devs, since a vast majority of the other operators are accounted for. I suppose this is something you could suggest to the Visual Studio team as well, but I'm not sure how much success you'd have.

Extending the above, you could opt instead to use the `+=` or `-=` operators, which have auto spacing capability. Rather than:

```
int i = 0; i ++;
```

You would have:

```
int i = 0; i += 1;
```

Which is functionally equivalent and no less right or wrong than using the increment/decrement operator to begin with. I'm not sure if Visual Studio has this functionality out of the box, but if you're willing to ditch the ++/-- it may be worth a look.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah I concede it's atypical, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious.  I use Resharper, but I agree it wouldn't do much good to submit an enhancement request if it's as rare as indicated throughout this question.  I suppose I could go the macro/plugin route if I were truly bent on implementing this.  Cheers :)

Comment: That, or change operators, though you do lose some readability. I don't think it would be too outlandish of a suggestion considering they have most of the other operators handled; What's fair is fair, right! There are some left off by default, so it wouldn't be that big of a deal to add one more.